# Selecting dynamic elements id on loops

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am new to js and jquery and need some helps.
I have data that return from database by php like :

```
foreach ($form as $value) {
  $input = '<input type="number" id="tbpersentase'.$i.'" min="0" max="100" value="'.$value->persentase.'" title="Progres">';
  $inputdnone = '<input type="number" id="persentase'.$i.'" min="0" max="100" value="'.$value->persentase.'">'; //this input should not appear in view
  $i++;
}
 $row = '<input type="number" id="formJum" value="'.$i.'">';
```

the html result I want may like this:

```
<input id="tbpersentase0" value="myVal">
<input id="persentase0" value="myVal">
<input id="tbpersentase1" value="myVals">
<input id="persentase1" value="myVals">
...
// and so on as many as the data retrieve from db
<input id="formJum" value="rowCount">
```

In my project it needs to be when input with `id='"tbpersentase"$i'` value has been change by user, then the input with `id='"persentase"$i'` value change to whatever `id='"tbpersentase"$i'` value is.
I use some code like this :

```
var formJum = $('#formJum').val();
for(i=0; i<formJum; i++){
  $('#tbpersentase'+i).change(function(){
    var tbpersentase = $(this).val();
    $('#persentase'+i).val(tbpersentase);
  })
}
```

the browser is not giving any errors to me, so I think my code is done. But when I change the value of input with `id='"tbpersentase"$i'` the element `id='"persentase"$i'` value with the same `i` doesn't change.

My whole element code look like this :

```
<div class="col-sm-7 px-0 reportsForApps d-none">
  <div class="px-3">
    <table class="table dttables" id="dtForm"> // data-tables client side processing
      <thead class="d-none">
        <tr>
          <th class="d-none">-</th>
          <th class="d-none">-</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="inputform">
        // #tbpersentase goes here for user input ..
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id=""> // this doesnt appear to user page
    <input type="number" id="formJum" value="">
    </div>
    <div id="inputProgres"> // this doesnt appear to user page
      // #persentase goes here ..
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All the value and element set by ajax.
Any idea what I have to do with my code? thank you

Comment: why did you write change function in a loop? can you give an example using some value?

Comment: sorry I have update my question. the html result should be like that

Comment: okk I got it but what should be the user input? will the user give input in `<input id="formJum" value="rowCount">` this field only or every `#tbpersentase` field?

Comment: user will set the value to the input with id `'#tbpersentase'+i`. I use `#formJum` to know how many row I get from db, and how many `i` for the looping. if the data that I get is 12 records. so `#formJum` value set to 12. And max input form id is `'#tbpersentase11'` `'#persentase11'` (start index from 0)

Comment: I got it why you used `#formJum`. can you tell me what will happen after user input? say you have 12 rows & user input `#tbpersentase5` input field. do you want all the input field to be updated with the same value?

Comment: the input with id `#persentase5` (same index in looping) value changed to what `#tbpersentase5` value is. User set value `#tbpersentase5` to 88, so only `#persentase5` set to 88. the other input is not affected to the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `class` as selector as this can be same for multiple element. Use jQuery [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to store index.

```
$i=0;                                                                           
foreach ($form as $value) {
    $input = '<input type="number" class="percentage" data-index="'.$i.'" value="'.$value->persentase.'" min="0" max="100" title="Progres">';
    $inputdnone = '<input type="number" id="persentase'.$i.'" min="0" max="100" value="'.$value->persentase.'">'; //this input should not appear in view
    $i++;                                                                                 
}
```

In jQuery Part, no need to use loop just write change function for `percentage` class. This will be triggered whenever a value of an input is changed:

```
$(".reportsForApps").on("change", ".percentage", function(){ // 'parentElementId' should be replaced with actual parent element id.
    var tbpersentase = $(this).val(); 
    var index = $(this).data("index");
    $('#persentase'+index).val(tbpersentase);                                       
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. But in my case it seem doesn't work. Is it because I pass the input html by ajax?

Comment: yes. you need to use `on()`. I am editing my answer.

Comment: I got what you mean. But still not working to my code.

Comment: @far1023 can you show the parent element/html of the dynamic/ajax-rendered controls?

Comment: @AsifRahaman you need to change the event binding context from `percentage` class to the parent static element (which i asked in above comment).

Comment: `on` has no impact if the contextual element is lazy rendered.

Comment: @SangSuantak I dont know if it is make it more clear. I put the `#tbpersentase` in datatable table row. And `#persentase` in other div where user cant see it (similar like div.d-none in bootstrap). I've update my question

Comment: @far1023 change the line from this answer `$("#parentElementId").on("change", ".percentage", function(){`     to this     `$(".reportsForApps").on("change", ".percentage", function(){`. It should work now.

Comment: Finally it works. Thank you, have nice day stay safe.

Comment: @SangSuantak I just returned from lunch and saw that you edited my answer. thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute that code on every #formJum value change using the change() function.

Also would be better if you dispose properly those event handlers in every input change.

Comment: Can you give more specific info please? I use `#formJum` to get how many data row that retrieve from db. And `#formJum` value to select on as many as element with `#tbpersentase+i`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a data-type attr `data-group="tbpersentase"` and call on it in your function

```
$input = null;
$inputdnone = null;

foreach ($form as $key => $value) { // you could also use $key value for increment
    $input .= '<input type="number" data-group="tbpersentase" id="tbpersentase'.$key.'" min="0" max="100" value="'.$value.'" title="Progres">';
    $inputdnone .= '<input type="hidden" id="persentase'.$key.'" min="0" max="100" value="'.$value.'">'; //this input should not appear in view
}
 // place in html to echo results of dynamically created inputs from DB info
 <?=$input?>
 <?=$inputdnone?>

// JQuery 3.4.1
$( "input[data-group='tbpersentase']" ).change(function() {
  var $this = $(this).val(); // get users value of the changing input field
  var tbpersentaseID = $(this).attr('id'); // get the changing input fields ID so we can remove IDs alpha chars
  var getID = tbpersentaseID.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''); // declare a new variable containing the numbers for the selected ID
  var persentaseID = 'persentase' + getID; // Concatenate desired alpha ID name to selected key value 

  $("#"+persentaseID).val($this); // set value

});
```

Tested in chrome and changes value of `#persentase` to the value entered in `#tbpersentase` yet retains original ID in `#persentase`. Hope this is what you were looking to achieve.

[image]

Also, if you want to know how many rows you get from DB, use `count()` in php.

```
$form_count = count($form);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it is not working to my code.